# Call to undefined method DB_Class::prepare()

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I know this probably has been asked before, but the answers in other topics I found didn't seem to help for me :/. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong when I follow the answers but its bugging me out.

The error: Call to undefined method DB_Class::prepare()  on line 15. I've put a comment line to mark it.

The code is in Dutch, I hope that ain't a problem.

Reg_Functies.php (or the relevant part atleast):

```
<?php
require_once("Reg_Config.php");
class Gebruiker
{
    private $db;

    public function Gebruiker()
    {
        $this->db = new DB_Class();
    }

    public function check_login($email, $wachtwoord) 
    {
        $wachtwoord = md5($wachtwoord);
        $resultaat = $this->db->prepare("SELECT Log_ID, Log_Bevoegdheid from login WHERE Log_Email = ? and Log_Wachtwoord = ?"); //this line gives the error

        $resultaat->bind_param("ss", $email, $wachtwoord);
        $resultaat->execute();
```

Reg_Config.php:

```
<?php
define('DB_Server', 'localhost');
define('DB_Gebruikersnaam', 'root');
define('DB_Wachtwoord', 'password');
define('DB_Database', 'database');
class DB_Class 
{
    function __construct() 
    {
        $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_Server, DB_Gebruikersnaam, DB_Wachtwoord, DB_Database);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
    }
}
```

?>

It's probably something very simple I'm looking over, but help is really appreciated.

Comment: You `DB_Class` class does not have any methods beyond the constructor, and it does not inheret from anything. Yet you try and call methods on it `$this->db->....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is trying to call `DB_Class::prepare()`, because `$this->db` has been assigned `new DB_Class()`.

First, your constructor should keep a copy of the `mysqli` connection object, so add a field

```
private $connection;
```

to the `DB_Class` class, and update the constructor so that it calls

```
$this->connection = $connection;
```

at the end.

Then, you either need to define a `prepare` method that calls `mysqli_prepare($this->connection)` in `DB_Class()`, or call `$this->db->connection->prepare()`. If you choose the last option, you need to make it a `public` field, instead!

Another, much better option, is to avoid creating this redundant `DB_Class` and use `PDO` instead.

Comment: `$connection` is a local variable within the constructors scope (and therefor immediately discarded), no a public property, so `$this->db->connection` is not an option. I agree with you re PDO though